# R: can I create an object with meaningless parameter and then use it inside a function that, using its input arguments, will give it meaning?

Tags: r, ggplot2, variables, global-variables, parameter-passing

Is it possible to create a list containing meaningless parameter, like `fill.var` in the list `design <- list( geom_boxplot(aes(fill=fill.var), na.rm=TRUE), theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 20, face = "bold"), legend.position = "bottom"), )`  and then give this parameter meaning inside a function as an argument, like that:

```
general_plot <- function(df,x.var,y.var,fill.var){
  ggplot(data=df, aes(x={{x.var}}, y={{y.var}}, fill={{fill.var}}))+design
}

plot_generator(subset_table,treatment,size,treatment)
```

When I tried to write it like that I got an error saying `` object `fill.var` not found `` when running the function, Also when I tried `design<-list(geom_boxplot(aes(fill=!fill.var)))`.
When I tried `design<-list(geom_boxplot(aes(fill=!!fill.var)))` and `design<-list(geom_boxplot(aes(fill={{fill.var}})))` I got the error when running the `design` object before even trying to use it in the function.

I would much rather solve it like that, but I'm also OK with creating a default `fill.var` and excess it from the function argument, which I couldn't figure out how...

tnx!

Comment: You can set a user-defined function argument to NULL like `fill.var = NULL` and this could possibly solve your problem. See if that creates the desired effect.

Comment: thank u @Quinton.Quagliano, but for some reason the `fill.var` argument of the function is not masking or excessing the global `fill.var`, and the function creates white plots, which I assume is its interpretation of NULL fill...?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [quasiquotation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rlang/versions/0.2.2/topics/quasiquotation) in combination with [tidyevaluation](https://dcl-prog.stanford.edu/tidy-eval-detailed.html):

###### Quasiquotation is the combination of quoting an expression while allowing immediate evaluation (unquoting) of part of that expression.

##### 1. using `!!` `bang bang operator`

`sym()` to convert the variable names from strings to symbols.

`!!` to unquote the symbols so that ggplot recognizes them as column names

```
library(ggplot2)
library(rlang)

general_plot <- function(df, x.var, y.var, fill.var) {
  # Creating symbols
  x.var <- sym(x.var)
  y.var <- sym(y.var)
  fill.var <- sym(fill.var)
  
  design <- list(
    geom_boxplot(aes(fill = !!fill.var), na.rm = TRUE), 
    theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 20, face = "bold"), legend.position = "bottom")
  )
  
  ggplot(data = df, aes(x = !!x.var, y = !!y.var)) + design
}

general_plot(diamonds, "cut", "price", "color")
```

##### 2. using `{{}}` `curly curly`

```
library(ggplot2)
library(rlang)

general_plot <- function(df, x.var, y.var, fill.var) {
  design <- list(
    geom_boxplot(aes(fill = {{ fill.var }}), na.rm = TRUE),
    theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 20, face = "bold"), legend.position = "bottom")
  )
  
  ggplot(data = df, aes(x = {{ x.var }}, y = {{ y.var }})) + design
}

general_plot(diamonds, cut, price, color)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank u @TarJae, but both of these solutions include inserting the design list into the plot function. I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to keep the list outside the function even in the price of having an argument that is meaningless outside the function in that list?